# How can I easily hide all transport controls in UWP MediaPlayerElement except a few?

Tags: c#, uwp, controls, media-player, uwp-xaml

I have a MediaPlayerElement that plays a video automatically and I want the user to be only able to seek in the video and press pause/stop/play.

It looks like I have to set `AreTransportControlsEnabled` to `true` and then hide all the controls I don't want one by one as per default all controls are visible.

So I did this:

```
<MediaPlayerElement x:Name="mediaPlayer" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True">
            <MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
                <MediaTransportControls
                    ShowAndHideAutomatically="True"
                    IsFullWindowButtonVisible="False"
                    IsNextTrackButtonVisible="False"
                    IsPreviousTrackButtonVisible="False"
                    IsVolumeButtonVisible="False"
                    IsZoomButtonVisible="False"
                    IsFastForwardButtonVisible="False"
                    IsFastRewindButtonVisible="False"
                    IsPlaybackRateButtonVisible="False"
                    IsRepeatButtonVisible="False"
                    IsSkipBackwardButtonVisible="False"
                    IsSkipForwardButtonVisible="False"
                    Windows10version1803:IsCompactOverlayButtonVisible="False"
                    IsSeekBarVisible="True"
                    IsSeekEnabled="True"
                    IsStopButtonVisible="True"
                    />
            </MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
        </MediaPlayerElement>
```

For my taste this looks really cumbersome. Isn't there are setting like "hideall=true" and then I could only enable those I want. And for example, there seems to be no way to also hide the "cast to device" button, so with the current approach the user would always see this button, what I don't really like:
[image: Example with 'cast to device' button visible]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing "CastButton" from generic.xaml didn't work out for me. I found a solution for removing Cast to Device button in another forum :
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e3307864-f194-4197-9f0d-bb2b8cd7228c/uwp-custom-media-transport-controls-hide-custom-buttons

Here is the working code for removing "CastButton" AppBarButton from Mediaplayer at runtime.

```
public class CustomMediaTransportControls: MediaTransportControls
{
    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    { 
        AppBarButton CastButton = GetTemplateChild("CastButton") as AppBarButton;

        var MediaControlsCommandBar = GetTemplateChild("MediaControlsCommandBar") as CommandBar;
        MediaControlsCommandBar.PrimaryCommands.Remove(CastButton); 
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution worked great and I like that you don't have to copy the control styles to your project.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own media transport controls by setting AreTransportControlsEnabled to false, and using the Play and Pause methods on [MediaPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer).

For more info and examples, see [Create custom transport controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls).

The official [Media transport controls sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlCustomMediaTransportControls) will be a good start.

For example, in the official sample, if you do not want to show the 'cast to device' button, you could directly remove the `AppBarButton` named as CastButton in the generic.xaml.